# AWS lambda layers

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, openpyxl

I am trying to use pandas with an AWS lambda function. I downloaded pandas, numpy, pytz, xlrd, and openpyxl from pypi.org, unpacked them, and zipped them all up in a python folder. Then i created a new layer in AWS, uploaded the zip, applied the layer to my lambda function, but i still get this error:

```
  "errorMessage": "Missing optional dependency 'openpyxl'.  Use pip or conda to install openpyxl.",
```

I got the same error earlier before uploading the layer, but then i was missing pandas. This got resolved with uploadind the layer, but then i got the error above. I am not sure where i am doing something wrong here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you downloaded your ZIP layer to check its contents? It should have a single root folder called "python" and your requirements should be installed inside it.

Comment: Yes, my ZIP layer only has 1 root folder called "python" and all the libraries downloaded and unpacked from pypi.org are inside it. Somehow my layer is working for pandas, but not openpyxl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a new layer using an already existing one with ARN found here: https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers/blob/master/deployments/python3.8/arns/eu-central-1.csv

That solved my problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).